# Linux, C++, Lua 5.3, CMake, undefined reference

Tags: c++, lua, cmake

I'm trying to use Lua in my C++ program. My OS is Linux Manjaro 15.12. I downloaded the Lua 5.3 source code, and compiled it as C++ code (I really need the exception handling instead of longjmp), with this line:

```
make "CC=g++" linux
```

Then *sudo make install* to get Lua installed in /usr/local. Everything looks fine. My CMake version seems to be updated:

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.4.1
```

In my CMake file, I find Lua like this:

```
find_package(Lua REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})

message("   *** Lua include: ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("   *** Lua lib: ${LUA_LIBRARIES}")
```

After running this command:

```
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

The include folder is properly detected in /usr/local/include, but the library itself, is found as /usr/lib64/liblua5.1.so;/usr/lib64/libm.so, wich is not the installation I did (and its version 5.1, I want 5.3). CMake says:

```
Found Lua: /usr/lib64/liblua5.1.so;/usr/lib64/libm.so (found version "5.3.2")
```

Its like it is "mixing" the two versions. Running *make* throws a lot of undefined references. Previously in my CMake file, I find other libraries (SDL2 compiled by me, OpenGL, glew), and they seem to work. The only errors I got are for the Lua library. Of course, I'm adding the libraries to my *target_link_libraries* command

How can I fix this? (I don't care if I have to eliminate the older Lua version, as long as it doesn't break my OS).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by setting Lua library path manually:

```
CMAKE_ARGS:="-DLUA_LIBRARY=[Your Lua 5.3 so installation path]\;dl"
```

Comment: I fixed it by specifying the library version
`find_package(Lua 5.3 REQUIRED)`
thanks anyway